# jQuery - how to add css or hide a element after this element has been added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i have a question as title, i want add css or hide a element after this element has been added to DOM.
 - i know a way to add attribute to a element when it's has been created with jquery :

```
$('body').on('click','#newElement',function() {})
```

but it must click a newElement to can do this function.

```js
<script>
var h_notepad = 500;
var w_notepad = 737;
var data = [
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_1.png", hide_canvas : 0},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_2.png", hide_canvas : 0},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_3.png", hide_canvas : 1},
  {dataImageURL: "1_sat_4.png", hide_canvas : 0}
];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){

  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = w_notepad;
    canvas.height = h_notepad;
    $('body').append(canvas); 
    //how to hide and AddClass for canvas ?
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
  };
  img.src = data[i].dataImageURL;
//how to hide and addClass for canvas with data[i].hide_cavas after canvas has been added to DOM?  
  }
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DRAWING</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks .

Comment: why not do it in the onload handler

Comment: i try do it, but i can't get data[i].hide_cavans in onload handler.

Comment: Also `data.forEach(function(data) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = w_notepad;
    canvas.height = h_notepad;
    $(canvas).toggle(!data.hide_canvas).appendTo('body');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
  };
  img.src = data.dataImageURL;
});
`

Comment: OK thanks you, i will try do it.